# Load content below full width slideshow related to current slide when scrolled down

Tags: jquery, ajax, slideshow

I have created a full page slideshow which each slide is a hero image for various articles. 
The idea is that you navigate the articles by swiping the slideshow left and right, and then to read the content for each, you simple scroll down.
So what I need to happen, is external html files to be loaded into a div below the slideshow, which has to correspond with the current slide.

the slideshow gives the active slide a class named .rsActiveSlide, and I use this to acquire the current article id.

Here is my jquery

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var currentCaseStudy = $(".rsActiveSlide").children(".rsContent").attr("id");
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 5) {
            $( "#caseStudy" ).load( "case-studies/" + currentCaseStudy + ".html" );
        }
    });
```

Not only is this clumbsy but as its listening for every scroll event, it repeatedly loads the same content into the div over and over. so i'm wandering what the best solution for this is?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem in the end.... I used inview.js plugin, and used that to trigger the content load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.caseLoader.loading').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible == true) {
        var currentCaseStudy = $(".rsActiveSlide").children(".rsContent").attr("id");
        $( "#caseStudy" ).load( "case-studies/" + currentCaseStudy + ".html" );
        $(this).removeClass('loading');
        $("#caseStudy").removeClass('loading');

    } else {
    }
});


}); // doc ready
```

but if anyone has a better way to do this then i'd love to hear their solution.

(to clear the content, I am simply emptying the div's contents when slide is changed)